# How to Validate 4 Sequential Button Clicks (WPF Application)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

What I am having trouble figuring out:
- How to capture 4 button clicks and check if they match the correct sequence similar to entering a 4 digit ATM debit card PIN number

I have a WPF Application and added a new Window that has a PIN pad, numbers 0-9, a question mark button (used as a help button), a backspace button (in case you clicked the wrong number), a TextBox at the top which displays a dot instead of the number (Wingdings - letter 'l'), and a hidden TextBlock which would show an Incorrect PIN message if the numbers were not entered in the correct order. For the time being, I am just going to hard code the 4 digit PIN (7410 for example) since my main goal is learning how to capture and validate the button click sequence. Since I will not be using an Enter key button, I want to continue to the next page as soon as the last number is clicked and the sequence was correct, else display the notification message that the PIN is incorrect. I will also put code in to not allow anything except mouse clicks work and limit the TextBox to only allow a max of 4 digits.

I'm guessing I need a method that is called on each button click which keeps track of the sequence and loops back through each time until all 4 numbers are clicked in the correct sequence then moves on to the next page. Sorry if I'm not explaining well, still learning, so if you need more details I'll do my best to give more.

Thank you in advance.

Below is the xaml code for the PIN pad.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Border Background="Black" Height="50" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock x:Name="PINTextBlock" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" FontFamily="Wingdings" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="4" />
        </Border>

        <TextBlock x:Name="ErrorMessageTextBlock" Foreground="Red" Visibility="Collapsed" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" />

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="2">
            <Button x:Name="SevenButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="SevenButton_Click" TabIndex="9">
                <TextBlock Text="7" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="EightButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="EightButton_Click" TabIndex="10">
                <TextBlock Text="8" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="NineButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="NineButton_Click" TabIndex="11">
                <TextBlock Text="9" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="3">
            <Button x:Name="FourButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="FourButton_Click" TabIndex="6">
                <TextBlock Text="4" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="FiveButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="FiveButton_Click" TabIndex="7">
                <TextBlock Text="5" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="SixButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="SixButton_Click" TabIndex="8">
                <TextBlock Text="6" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="4">
            <Button x:Name="OneButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="OneButton_Click" TabIndex="3">
                <TextBlock Text="1" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="TwoButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="TwoButton_Click" TabIndex="4">
                <TextBlock Text="2" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="ThreeButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="ThreeButton_Click" TabIndex="5">
                <TextBlock Text="3" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="5">
            <Button x:Name="QuestionMarkButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="QuestionMarkButton_Click" TabIndex="0">
                <TextBlock Text="?" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="ZeroButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="ZeroButton_Click" TabIndex="1">
                <TextBlock Text="0" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
            <Button x:Name="BackspaceButton" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="50" Height="50" Click="BackspaceButton_Click" TabIndex="2">
                <TextBlock Text="Õ" FontFamily="Wingdings" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the validation using Xaml and converters. All you have to do is;

- Use binding with ErrorTextBlock and listen for PinTextBlock.Text and run it through converter which will do the actual validation.

This way the validation logic will be seperated nicely and will be reusable. There are other WPF inbuilt validation ways and you can google about them. (IDataErrorInfo and ValidationRules).  This would be the "WPF" way.

But the learning curve is little steep. If you just wanna finish this thing, then yes, add this to StackPanel:  Button.Click="buttonClickHandler", and in code-behind you will be recieve every button you click in single place. And do your calculations there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely do some research about the built in WPF validation you suggested! I did as you suggested, added ButtonBase.Click="myHandler" to each StackPanel and, just as a quick test, put a MessageBox in the code behind and was able to capture each button click so I should be able to use this as a good starting point. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I would have a string that gets appended to (or modified in the case of `Backspace` or `Clear`) with each button click, and base my validation off if that string is 4 characters long and equals the PIN #

If it's 4 characters and matches, move to next page. If it's 4 characters and doesn't match, display the error message.

I know this is a learning application, but I'd highly recommend learning the MVVM design pattern if you will be working with WPF.

In that case, I'd have something like a `List<KeyValuePair<string, ICommand>> Buttons` that gets bound to an `ItemsControl` with an `ItemsPanelTemplate` set to a `UniformGrid` with 3 rows and 3 columns, and the `ItemTemplate` set to a `Button` that binds the Content to the `Key` and the Command to the `Value`, and an `bool IsErrorDisplayed` value that gets set to true anytime the error message should be displayed.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ErrorMessageTextBlock" Foreground="Red" 
           Visibility="{Binding IsErrorDisplayed, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibiltyConverter}}" 
           Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="1" />

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}">
    <!-- ItemsPanelTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" Rows="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

    <!-- ItemTemplate -->
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Width="50" Height="50" Command="{Binding Value}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="24" FontWeight="Bold" />
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

I'd also probably do something to secure the PIN # so isn't being stored as plain text.

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much for adding this suggestion as I was actually going to take this route with another part of my application. This answered a couple questions I was going to have to look up when I got to that part but since you suggested it I'm going to try it here as well! About securing and storing the PIN #, I have been researching the security and as soon as I have a good handle on my current situation, I'm going to move it so that users can create their own, hash it and store it elsewhere. Security is the most important! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Associate them all to the same event handler.  In that event uselogic to associate the x:Name with an Integer and  build up the 4 digit PIN.  This just lets you consolidate logic.

```
        private void one_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            Int32 num;
            switch (btn.Name)
            {
                case "one":
                    num = 1;
                    break;
                case "two":
                    num = 2;
                    break;
                default:
                    // problem
            }
            if (PIN > 1000)   // logic
            // now you have you have num and can deal with the logic in one click event;
            PIN = (PIN * 10) + num;
            if (PIN = correctPIN)
            {
            }
            else
            {
            }          
        }
```

Comment: Although I have it working now, I would still like to try your suggestion to see all different possibilities (never a bad thing to have more knowledge!). If you have time though, do you mind giving a short example please? Maybe just a couple buttons and the event and logic? Thank you too, I really appreciate your help as well.